# How to generete NCLOB instead of CLOB using @Lob?

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have the following field:

**Entity**

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "schema_ERD")
private String schemaERD;
```

**DBeaver (oracle)**

[image]

**How can i force that entity to genere NCLOB instead of CLOB?**

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
@Nationalized
@Lob
@Column(name = "schema_ERD")
private String schemaERD;
```